# Makefile fails with warning message

Tags: c, makefile

This is a makefile that fails to link the .o files to make an executeable.

```
enter code here
CC = c99
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra -O0
OBJECTS = main.o getoptions.o
P = testprog

$(P): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(P)

main.o : main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -c main.c

getoptions.o : getoptions.c getoptions.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c getoptions.o
```

I get this warning:

```
gcc: warning: getoptions.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

When I manually use:

```
c99 *.o -o testprog
```

linking succeeds.

Comment: Is it a typo? Should the last row be `getoptions.c`?

Comment: Also the rule for `main.o` is wrong: it shouldn't contain `$(OBJECTS)`. Why don't you just let make's builtin rules handle it for you, instead of writing your own explicit rules?

Comment: if you run the makefile with the '-d' option, then you will see the problem with the posted rule for compiling main.c into main.o.   Suggest getting very familiar with the make capabilities, so your makefiles are 'elegant' and much more capable of handling many different situations/projects with much less actual lines of rules in the make file.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

First, in your target for `getoptions.o`, you're passing `getoptions.o` for the `-c` option.  You should be giving it the value of the source file `getoptions.c`

Second, get rid of `$(OBJECTS)` in the target for `main.o`.  You don't need to pass in the object files for this step.

With those fixes you'll get a successful compilation:

```
c99 -g -Wall -Wextra -O0 -c main.c
c99 -g -Wall -Wextra -O0 -c getoptions.c
c99 main.o getoptions.o -o testprog
```

Edit:

The target line for main.o should be:

```
main.o : main.c getoptions.h
```

That way, if `getoptions.h` changes, `main.o` gets rebuilt.

Comment: well, not quite.   the compiler should be told where the header file is located.   appending a '-I.' parameter to the c99 ... line in the compiling of getoptions.c would fix that.  I would expect the last line of the make file to be: $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c getoptions.c -o getoptions.o -I.   BTW: where did c99 become the compiler.   Normally one of the compile and link parameters would be '-std=c99' and the $CC would be set to 'gcc' or perhaps '/usr/lib/gcc'.

Comment: How is the compiler expected to know the prototypes of the functions in getoptions.c without also including the header file: getoptions.h?  If getoptions.h is changed, main.c will not be recompiled because that header file is not listed in the dependancies

Comment: @user40831 Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. Answered I think.

Comment: @user40831 glad I could help.  Feel free to accept this answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot.